# How to move to the tail all elements that stay before the defined element in LinkedList?

Tags: java, queue, linked-list, tail

I have a question regarding `LinkedList` that I'm using to implement a queue. How to move to the tail all elements that stay before the defined element? Let's say I need to move to the tail all elements that stay before the 3rd element (see the below example). It means that the numbers `1` and `2` should be moved to the tail in order to get: `3->4->1->2`.

Is it possible to do something similar to `list1.moveToTheTail(startElem,endElem);` where `startElem` and `endElem` indicate bounds of elements to be moved to the tail?

`import java.util.LinkedList`;

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list1.addLast(1);
        list1.addLast(2);
        list1.addLast(3);
        list1.addLast(4);
        list1.
        System.out.println(list1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there is no such function .. it's a pity because the operation move from front to tail  is only a change of the "pointer" to the first element.

But you want a function to move also from the middle of the list ... here we go:

```
public static void moveToTail(LinkedList<?> list,int startElement, int endElement) {
    if (startElement <0 )
        return ;
    if (endElement < startElement)
        return;
    if (endElement >= list.size())
        return;
    for(int i = startElement ; i < endElement ; ++i) {
         //yeah it has to be startElement and not i
         list.addLast(list.remove(startElement));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I currently use a lot of programming languages and write the code only here in the textbox .. changed the `function` to `public static void` ..

Answer (score 1):

Remove them, and re-add them, starting from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [poll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll%28%29) and [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add%28E%29) methods to move the elements from the head to the tail of the `Queue`:

```
public static void moveToTail(int nElements, Queue<?> queue) {
    // Do some checkings here if necessary
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nElements ; ++i) {
        queue.add(queue.poll());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, it will modify the list in place:

```
public static <T> List<T> moveToTheTail(List<T> list, int startElem, int endElem) {
    for (int i = startElem; i < endElem; i++)
        list.add(list.remove(startElem));
    return list;
}
```

The above method assumes that the indexes are valid for the list. Use it like this:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(4);

list1 = moveToTheTail(list1, 0, 2);
System.out.println(list1);
```

All the elements between the index startElem and less than endElem will be removed from the list and added to the end. And  since it uses generics, it works for any class that implements the `List` interface containing elements of any type.